# Connect iOS app to sockJs server using swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, mobile, sockjs

I am working on iOS app and I have to connect my app to sockJS server to get live feed. Is there any sockJS client available for iOS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Connected successfully to SockJS using the following :)**

1. Place a UIWebView and set its visibility to hidden.
2. Use SockJS client in webview.
3. Use UIWebViewDelegate.
4. We have to call the JS function only once from native swift code.

**ViewController:**

```
func initWebView(){
    webView = UIWebView()
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height-120, self.view.frame.width, 58)
    if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("template", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "web") {
        let requestURL = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        //print("request\(requestURL)")
        webView!.delegate = self
        webView!.loadRequest(requestURL)
    }
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    print("WebView Loaded")
    if self.webViewLoaded == false {
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("connectToSocket('\(self.serverUrl)','\(self.accessKey)')");
        //print("Sock return: \(htmlTitle)")
    }
    self.webViewLoaded = true
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if request.URL!.scheme == "sockjs" {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: (request.URL?.absoluteString)!)
            let queryItems = urlComponents?.queryItems
            let param1 = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "msg"}).first
            let temp = String(param1!.value!)
            if let data = temp.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                let json = JSON(data: data)
                //print("Live Data: \(json)")
                self.updateMarkerInfo(json)
            }
        })
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

**template.html:**

Copy sockjs code in template.html, then add following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sock;
    function connectToSocket(url, accessKey){
        //alert("connectTosocket called!");
        this.sock = new SockJS(url);

        sock.onopen = function() {
            //alert("open");
            sock.send(JSON.stringify({
                key: accessKey
            }));
        };

        sock.onclose = function() {
            sock.close();
            alert("close");
        };

        sock.onmessage = function(e) {
            result = e.data.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            window.location = 'sockjs://data?msg='+ result
            //alert(result);
        };

        sock.onerror = function(e) {
            alert("error" + e);
        };
    }

    function closeConnection () {
       try {
          this.sock.close();
          }catch(err) {

         }
       }

     function sendMessage(message){
        sock.send(message);
     }


</script>
```

**Don't forget to add following in info.plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
         <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
         <true/>
    </dict>
```

https://github.com/vishal-raj/SockJSiOSClient

Comment: What do you mean by SockJS client in webview? can you please explain second point

Comment: Create a html file with SockJS client, and use that on webview.